# Android Gridview - skipped frames and Garbage Collection errors

Tags: android, performance, gridview, garbage-collection

To give a bit of context my app has 2 tabs. One of the tabs displays the name and image of all 151 pokemon from the game Pokemon Go in a GridView. The largest image being 50kb. Sometimes my app crashes and the log shows a bunch of GC messages:

```
I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.472ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 145MB to 129MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 129MB/129MB, paused 281us total 9.184ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 37.353ms for cause Alloc
```

When the app doesn't crash (I don't see why it would only sometimes crashes due to GC ) I get this:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I can see that the gridView is a touch laggy. I've researched and made changes to my code to make my gridview more efficient but it's still a tad laggy. I'm wondering if it's the way I'm storing my images. I'll post my main activity, The GridView Adapter and my Pokedex class which holds a list of pokemon objects that contain image and string resources. If you need more information let me know in the comments, thanks in advance.

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater  mInflater;

public GridAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return Pokedex.getNumberOfPokemon();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    Pokemon current = Pokedex.getPokemon(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.pokemonImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pokemon_image);
        holder.pokemonName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pokemon_name);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.pokemonImage.setImageResource(current.getImageResource());
    holder.pokemonName.setText(current.getNameResource());
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView pokemonImage;
    TextView pokemonName;
}
}
```

The pokedex class:

```
public class Pokedex {
private final static ArrayList<Pokemon> list = new ArrayList<Pokemon>();

public static int getNumberOfPokemon(){
    return list.size();
}

public static Pokemon getPokemon(int position){
    return list.get(position);
}

static{
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Bulbasaur, 1, R.drawable.bulbasaur));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Ivysaur, 2, R.drawable.ivysaur));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Venusaur, 3, R.drawable.venusaur));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Charmander, 4, R.drawable.charmander));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Charmeleon, 5, R.drawable.charmeleon));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Charizard, 6, R.drawable.charizard));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Squirtle, 7, R.drawable.squirtle));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Wartortle, 8, R.drawable.wartortle));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Blastoise, 9, R.drawable.blastoise));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Caterpie, 10, R.drawable.caterpie));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Metapod, 11, R.drawable.metapod));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Butterfree, 12, R.drawable.butterfree));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Weedle, 13, R.drawable.weedle));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Kakuna, 14, R.drawable.kakuna));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Beedrill, 15, R.drawable.beedrill));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Pidgey, 16, R.drawable.pidgey));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Pidgeotto, 17, R.drawable.pidgeotto));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Pidgeot, 18, R.drawable.pidgeot));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Rattata, 19, R.drawable.rattata));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Raticate, 20, R.drawable.raticate));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Spearow, 21, R.drawable.spearow));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Fearow, 22, R.drawable.fearow));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Ekans, 23, R.drawable.ekans));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Arbok, 24, R.drawable.arbok));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Pikachu, 25, R.drawable.pikachu));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Raichu, 26, R.drawable.raichu));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Sandshrew, 27, R.drawable.sandshrew));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Sandslash, 28, R.drawable.sandslash));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.NidoranF, 29, R.drawable.nidoranf));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Nidorina, 30, R.drawable.nidorina));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Nidoqueen, 31, R.drawable.nidoqueen));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.NidoranM, 32, R.drawable.nidoranm));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Nidorino, 33, R.drawable.nidorino));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Nidoking, 34, R.drawable.nidoking));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Clefairy, 35, R.drawable.clefairy));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Clefable, 36, R.drawable.clefable));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Vulpix, 37, R.drawable.vulpix));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Ninetales, 38, R.drawable.ninetales));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Jigglypuff, 39, R.drawable.jigglypuff));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Wigglytuff, 40, R.drawable.wigglytuff));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Zubat, 41, R.drawable.zubat));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Golbat, 42, R.drawable.golbat));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Oddish, 43, R.drawable.oddish));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Gloom, 44, R.drawable.gloom));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Vileplume, 45, R.drawable.vileplume));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Paras, 46, R.drawable.paras));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Parasect, 47, R.drawable.parasect));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Venonat, 48, R.drawable.venonat));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Venomoth, 49, R.drawable.venomoth));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Diglett, 50, R.drawable.diglett));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Dugtrio, 51, R.drawable.dugtrio));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Meowth, 52, R.drawable.meowth));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Persian, 53, R.drawable.persian));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Psyduck, 54, R.drawable.psyduck));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Golduck, 55, R.drawable.golduck));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Mankey, 56, R.drawable.mankey));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Primeape, 57, R.drawable.primeape));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Growlithe, 58, R.drawable.growlithe));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Arcanine, 59, R.drawable.arcanine));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Poliwag, 60, R.drawable.poliwag));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Poliwhirl, 61, R.drawable.poliwhirl));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Poliwrath, 62, R.drawable.poliwrath));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Abra, 63, R.drawable.abra));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Kadabra, 64, R.drawable.kadabra));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Alakazam, 65, R.drawable.alakazam));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Machop, 66, R.drawable.machop));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Machoke, 67, R.drawable.machoke));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Machamp, 68, R.drawable.machamp));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Bellsprout, 69, R.drawable.bellsprout));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Weepinbell, 70, R.drawable.weepinbell));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Victreebel, 71, R.drawable.victreebel));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Tentacool, 72, R.drawable.tentacool));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Tentacruel, 73, R.drawable.tentacruel));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Geodude, 74, R.drawable.geodude));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Graveler, 75, R.drawable.graveler));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Golem, 76, R.drawable.golem));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Ponyta, 77, R.drawable.ponyta));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Rapidash, 78, R.drawable.rapidash));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Slowpoke, 79, R.drawable.slowpoke));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Slowbro, 80, R.drawable.slowbro));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Magnemite, 81, R.drawable.magnemite));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Magneton, 82, R.drawable.magneton));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Farfetchd, 83, R.drawable.farfetchd));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Doduo, 84, R.drawable.doduo));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Dodrio, 85, R.drawable.dodrio));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Seel, 86, R.drawable.seel));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Dewgong, 87, R.drawable.dewgong));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Grimer, 88, R.drawable.grimer));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Muk, 89, R.drawable.muk));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Shellder, 90, R.drawable.shellder));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Cloyster, 91, R.drawable.cloyster));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Gastly, 92, R.drawable.gastly));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Haunter, 93, R.drawable.haunter));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Gengar, 94, R.drawable.gengar));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Onix, 95, R.drawable.onix));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Drowzee, 96, R.drawable.drowzee));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Hypno, 97, R.drawable.hypno));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Krabby, 98, R.drawable.krabby));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Kingler, 99, R.drawable.kingler));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Voltorb, 100, R.drawable.voltorb));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Electrode, 101, R.drawable.electrode));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Exeggcute, 102, R.drawable.exeggcute));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Exeggutor, 103, R.drawable.exeggutor));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Cubone, 104, R.drawable.cubone));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Marowak, 105, R.drawable.marowak));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Hitmonlee, 106, R.drawable.hitmonlee));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Hitmonchan, 107, R.drawable.hitmonchan));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Lickitung, 108, R.drawable.lickitung));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Koffing, 109, R.drawable.koffing));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Weezing, 110, R.drawable.weezing));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Rhyhorn, 111, R.drawable.rhyhorn));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Rhydon, 112, R.drawable.rhydon));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Chansey, 113, R.drawable.chansey));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Tangela, 114, R.drawable.tangela));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Kangaskhan, 115, R.drawable.kangaskhan));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Horsea, 116, R.drawable.horsea));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Seadra, 117, R.drawable.seadra));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Goldeen, 118, R.drawable.goldeen));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Seaking, 119, R.drawable.seaking));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Staryu, 120, R.drawable.staryu));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Starmie, 121, R.drawable.starmie));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.MrMime, 122, R.drawable.mrmime));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Scyther, 123, R.drawable.scyther));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Jynx, 124, R.drawable.jynx));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Electabuzz, 125, R.drawable.electabuzz));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Magmar, 126, R.drawable.magmar));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Pinsir, 127, R.drawable.pinsir));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Tauros, 128, R.drawable.tauros));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Magikarp, 129, R.drawable.magikarp));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Gyarados, 130, R.drawable.gyarados));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Lapras, 131, R.drawable.lapras));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Ditto, 132, R.drawable.ditto));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Eevee, 133, R.drawable.eevee));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Vaporeon, 134, R.drawable.vaporeon));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Jolteon, 135, R.drawable.jolteon));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Flareon, 136, R.drawable.flareon));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Porygon, 137, R.drawable.porygon));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Omanyte, 138, R.drawable.omanyte));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Omastar, 139, R.drawable.omastar));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Kabuto, 140, R.drawable.kabuto));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Kabutops, 141, R.drawable.kabutops));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Aerodactyl, 142, R.drawable.aerodactyl));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Snorlax, 143, R.drawable.snorlax));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Articuno, 144, R.drawable.articuno));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Zapdos, 145, R.drawable.zapdos));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Moltres, 146, R.drawable.moltres));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Dratini, 147, R.drawable.dratini));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Dragonair, 148, R.drawable.dragonair));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Dragonite, 149, R.drawable.dragonite));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Mewtwo, 150, R.drawable.mewtwo));
    list.add(new Pokemon(R.string.Mew, 151, R.drawable.mew));
}
}
```

MainActivity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;

        switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){
            case 1: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                break;
            }

            case 2: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grid, container, false);

                GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
                gridView.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(getActivity()));

                break;
            }
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Main Tab";
            case 1:
                return "Pokedex Gridview";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the [setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) method, which as stated in the docs runs in the UI thread, so the resource loading is synchronous:

> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.

So as stated there you should use the [setImageDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method (which I think loads the drawable asynchronously). Here is the way to get the drawable object in the "getView" method of your adapter: `getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable)`.
Remember that in Android the user interface is rendered in the main thread (hence its other name "UI Thread"), so you need to do the less possible work there (Android runs the render at 60 FPS). Because you are doing too much work in the UI thread (loading the resources) the system cannot maintain the 60 FPS, so skips many frames.

Comment: Thanks, however getDrawable is now deprecated so I used holder.pokemonImage.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(mContext.getResources(), current.getImageResource(), null)); instead which works but the gridview scroll still isn't super smooth. Maybe I'm expecting too much? It works fine, there's just the slightest delay when the gridview loads the next row and of course if I scroll fast it's still skipping frames.

Comment: Ohh I see, the problem here is that we are decoding the bitmap each time the "getView" method is called, so I think that in order to enhance the performance it's important to implement a cache manager. Check out this: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#memory-cache

Comment: The link describes a in memory (RAM) cache, but below is a disk cache. You should implement both (RAM cache is faster but little, disk is slower but extensive).

Comment: Another option also (but less efficient) is that you decode your image using a worker thread (but it'll be a better idea to use a worker thread and a cache system). Also if you don't want to do your own cache system you can use an image loading library like Glide (which implements its own cache and loading system): https://github.com/bumptech/glide